# Subdomain with hostname and wildcard certificate Not presenting certificate of CNAMEd Domain

Tags: certificate, wildcard, hostname, cname, mismatch

I have a root domain with a SAN wildcard subdomain certificate. There is a CNAME pointing to another domain with it's own wildcard subdomain with SANs to the former. The former certificate is presented instead of the latter.

Using a certificate checker like https://ssltools.godaddy.com/views/certChecker, I am seeing everything on the former's cert look good except for "Hostname mismatch" on Certificate names.

I would like to get the latter certificate to present though. I'm not sure why it isn't despite some similar testing with other domains.